# Velocity code generation: check whether $foreach is entered?

Tags: java, velocity

I try to modify a vsl file for code generation to check whether a foreach loop is actually entered and the initialization code is to be performed at all. I tried java-like .length > 0 but that does not work:

```
myMethod() {
    #if (${reference.attributes}.length > 0)
        [some init code]

        #foreach ($attribute in ${reference.attributes})
            #some_macro($attribute)
        #end
        [some other code related to stuff created in the 
    #end
}
```

What's the correct way?

Thanks.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly you need to run init code only once. You can set a variable during init and check if was already set. Like that


#if( $foo != "bar" )
 #set( $foo = "bar" )
 //do init here
#end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the `size()` method. This will work on both collections and arrays (as of Velocity 1.6+).

```
#if (${reference.attributes.size()} > 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#foreach ($foo in $bar)
    $foo
#end

Or if you want to iterate over a number range:

#foreach ($number in [1..34])
    $number
#end
```